# Regex to isolate trailing nested quote tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using some old PHP forum software that has been upgraded over the years, but during this process there are some posts that contain unrequited [QUOTE] blocks at the bottom of the post.

I'm trying to figure out a way to run a PHP preg_replace to Regex them out. I only want to remove QUOTE tags (which may also contain nested quote tags) that appear underneath the post content.

For example, a post to leave as-is may look like this:

```
Here is the example post text

[QUOTE]
This is an appropriate quote
[/QUOTE]

Here is more post content
```

On posts that look like the one below, I want to try and remove the last quote block:

```
Here is the example post text

[QUOTE]
This is an appropriate quote
[/QUOTE]

Here is more post content

[QUOTE]
This is an unnecessary quote, as it's below all of the post text
   [QUOTE]
   Here's an unnecessary nested quote, just to confuse things.
   [/QUOTE]
[/QUOTE]
```

I've spent hours trying to come up with a regex to capture quote blocks of the last type, to no avail. I know that I'll need to end with the following, as ending quotes will always have this tag at the end of the post:

```
\[\/QUOTE\]$
```

Is there a way I can capture the whole of the final QUOTE blocks in a regex, including any possible nested quotes? Anything I've tried so far will try and match a nested opening quote tag, as well as the final closing tag (rather than the matching pair).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a recursive, but ***anchored*** approach:

```
(\[QUOTE[^][]*\]
(?:[^][]++|(?1))++
\[/QUOTE\])
\Z
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/JyhSOp/1). Here, only the quote block in the end (`\Z`) is matched.

Comment: Wonderful - this is so simple and seems to work on all the cases I've tested so far! Thank you :).

Comment: I've rolled this out across the forum and it worked perfectly! I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284022/subpattern-regex-match-within-nested-quotes) and I was wondering if this regex could be modified to fit that too?

Comment: @user2874582: Yup, have provided a working answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284022/subpattern-regex-match-within-nested-quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can match the nested bb code at the end of the string like this.

`(?is)\[quote\]((?&core)|)\[/quote\]$(?(DEFINE)(?<core>(?>(?&content)|\[quote\](?:(?&core)|)\[/quote\])+)(?<content>(?>(?!\[/?quote\]).)+))`

demo:  https://regex101.com/r/uFPyXX/2

```
 (?is)

 \[quote\]                          # Start-Delimiter
 (                                  # (1), The CORE
      (?&core) 
   |  
 )
 \[/quote\]                         # End-Delimiter

 $                                  # End of string

 # ///////////////////////
 # // Subroutines
 # // ---------------

 (?(DEFINE)

      # core
      (?<core>
           (?>
                (?&content) 
             |  
                \[quote\]
                # recurse core
                (?:
                     (?&core)                           # Core
                  |                                   # or, nothing
                )
                \[/quote\]
           )+
      )

      # content 
      (?<content>
           (?>
                (?!
                     \[/?quote\]
                )
                . 
           )+
      )

 )
```

Note that if you need to qualify that an existing quote is before this
let me know and I'll give you a mod for it.