# Subpattern Regex match within nested quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm upgrading from some old forum software with lots of unnecessary nested [QUOTE] tags, which I would like to strip out via Regex (using PHP preg_replace). Most of these have already been done, but I'm struggling with the following type.

There are nested quote blocks within the post, but it's only necessary to retain the top level [QUOTE] content (as some of the nested quotes are 3 or 4 levels deep).

For example:

```
Here is some normal post content

[QUOTE]
This is an appropriate quote
[/QUOTE]

Here is more post content

[QUOTE]
This is a a valid quote, as it's only 1 level deep.
   [QUOTE="User 2"]
   Here's an unnecessary nested quote.
       [QUOTE]
       Here's a 3nd level unnecessary nested quote.
       [/QUOTE]
   [/QUOTE]
[/QUOTE]

Here is more post content
```

I'd like to strip out the 2nd and 3rd level nested quotes, but can't figure out how.

I had some excellent advice to [strip nested quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235352/regex-to-isolate-trailing-nested-quote-tags) entirely, but I've been unable to modify the regex pattern to fit this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you could use the same regex from the linked answer and apply it ***twice*** in conjunction with some programming logic:

```
<?php

$regex = '~
        (\[QUOTE[^][]*\]
        (?:[^][]++|(?1))++
        \[/QUOTE\])
        ~x';

$data = preg_replace_callback($regex, 
    function($match) use($regex) {
        return $match[0][0] . preg_replace($regex, '', substr($match[0], 1));
    },
    $your_data_string_here);

echo $data;
?>
```

---

This yields for your example:

```
Here is some normal post content

[QUOTE]
This is an appropriate quote
[/QUOTE]

Here is more post content

[QUOTE]
This is a a valid quote, as it's only 1 level deep.

[/QUOTE]

Here is more post content
```

---

The idea here is to match every quote tag (nested or not) and then apply the same expression to the matched string but with an offset of +1. When we take a substring, only the next nested set of `[QUOTE]` is found and then replaced.

A [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/JfT30g/1) and [**on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/s7Zvpy) clarifies this further.

Comment: What a clever way of doing this! Wonderfully simple solution. Thank you Jan :)

Comment: I've just done a test run across all of the posts and it looks like it works great, with one slight hiccup. If there's a square bracket in a nested quote (for example, for other tags) then it prevents that nested quote from being removed. Is there a workaround for this, or is this a necessary compromise?

Comment: @IanCun: I'd say it's getting complicated for edge cases and you'd probably be better using a parser instead. With that being said, you could **capture** the tag name and match it in the end like [**`\[(\w+)[^][]*\](?:[^][]++|(?R))++\[/\1\]`**](https://regex101.com/r/JyhSOp/2) - is this what you were after?

Comment: Many thanks @Jan. I Couldn't get this working unfortunately (https://ideone.com/6Xn10W), but may be able to strip those tags out in a separate regex and run the original script.

Answer (score 2):

With the same restrictions as the regex you linked (no other tags inside quotes) you can use

```
((?:\[QUOTE\]|\G(?!^))[^][]+)((\[QUOTE[^][]*\](?:[^][]++|(?2))++\[/QUOTE\]))
```

to search and then `$1` to replace only the nested quotes.

This basically matches the outmost quote in a separate group and only the inner quotes in the recursion, thus allowing to remove only them.

See https://regex101.com/r/y39Xaf/2

I have added a testcase with two different quotes inside an outer quote.

A little breakdown on the `((?:\[QUOTE\]|\G(?!^))[^][]+)`:

- everything is contained in a capturing group to allow to reinsert
- `(?:\[QUOTE\]|\G(?!^)` matches either literal `[QUOTE]` or the end of the previous match
- `[^][]+` matches any normal text

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, very clever that it can do this inside a single regex! I will test this now on some posts :)